# TYPO3 Menu with categories?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-9.x

How can I add the categories to each page of my menu element?

I have been trying different combinations of `DatabaseQueryProcessor` but the array comes through empty.

This is what I currently have based on other examples:

```
dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        10 {
             special = list
             special.value.field = pages
             levels = 2
             as = menuItems
             expandAll = 1
             includeNotInMenu = 1
             titleField = nav_title // title
             dataProcessing {
                 10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                 10 {
                     references.fieldName = media
                 }
                 20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
                 20 {
                        if.isTrue.field = categories
                        table = sys_category
                        pidInList = root,-1
                        selectFields = sys_category.*
                        where.data = field:_ORIG_uid // field:uid
                        as = categories
                 }
             }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete part inclusive MenuProcessor?

Comment: When I have problems with an empty DatabaseQueryProcessor SQL query I always provoke a SQL error by adding a wrong letter e.g. to the table name to get an output of the complete database query. Maybe that helps you as well.

Comment: @ThomasLöffler Added the MenuProcessor to the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pidInList needs to be the page where the categories are stored.

```
20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
20 {
        if.isTrue.field = categories
        table = sys_category
        selectFields = sys_category.*
        pidInList = 55
        recursive = 999
        join = sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = sys_category.uid
        where.data = field:_ORIG_uid // field:uid
        where.intval = 1
        where.wrap = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign=|
        as = categories
}
```